# how to get the div with text on another background image

Tags: html, css, css-position

I need to get the `div` content like this

[image]

Where "time" is the text on the `background-image`

Comment: If this is an image then you can target the _time_ with `background-position`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS Positioning techniques, here am doing nothing but nesting an element which is set to `position: absolute;` under the parent element which is set to `position: relative;`. Also am using `rgba` for opaque `border` and last but not the least am using `bottom` and `right` properties set to `0` to position the timer on the bottom right.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JgqKG/)

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 280px;
    background: url(http://pimg.tradeindia.com/00288122/b/0/Our-Valuable-Client-List-Click-on-Image-.jpg);
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    position: relative;
}

div span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```